# React-Native passing props without using navigator?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am wondering if it's possible to pass properties without using navigator?  What I am trying to do is pass a prop to a webview that is located in my index.ios.js.

Essentially what I have is an invisible iframe in my index.ios.js that allows a song to play throughout the app despite changing views, but I need to update the source for the WebView on a button press.

My index.ios.js looks like this:

```
class queueThat extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      source: ''
    };
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.iframe}>
        <WebView html={this.props.source} />
      </View>
      <React.NavigatorIOS
        style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={{
          title: 'queueThat',
          component: SearchPage, 
        }}/>
        </View>

    );
  }
}
```

My Search results page press function looks like:

```
  rowPressed(rowID) {
    this.setState({source: '<iframe width="100%" height="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/' + this.props.collection[rowID].id + '&amp;auto_play=true&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>'})
    console.log(this.state.source)
    this.props.navigator.push({
      passProps: {source: this.state.source}
    })
  }
```

I am trying to pass the source to the WebView html located in my index.ios.js without navigating away from the current view.
PS - I am very new to JS and React.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating set method in queueThat class and pass it to another component.

index.ios.js

```
class queueThat extends React.Component {

  ...

  // Your setSource method to update state from other component
  setSource = (source) => {
    this.setState({source: source});
  };

  render() {
    return (

      ...

      <React.NavigatorIOS
        style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={{
          title: 'queueThat',
          component: SearchPage, 
          passProps: { setSource: this.setSource }
        }}/>

      ...

    );
  }
}
```

Search result function

```
rowPressed(rowID) {

  ...

  //Calling parent component setSource method, which was passed through props
  this.props.setSource('Your new source');
}
```